# Understanding Decorators in Armeria

Tags: java, armeria

I am just starting out with Armeria and struggling to fully understand some things.

I implemented `DecoratingHttpServiceFunction` in order to supply requests to a service with a Hibernate session.

```java
@Override
public HttpResponse serve(HttpService delegate, ServiceRequestContext ctx, HttpRequest req) {
  ... // setup session for the request context
  HttpResponse response = delegate.serve(ctx, req);
  ... // close session
  return response;
}
```

But apparently the session gets closed before the service actually gets called and the request returned from `delegate.serve` is an instance of `DeferredHttpResponse`. Is my approach just completely wrong or is there a better way to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Armeria, all requests and responses are handled asynchronously. Therefore, returning from `delegate.serve(ctx, req)` in your code does not guarantee that the request has been fully processed.

To perform a certain action *after* a request is fully handled, you need to add a callback to the `HttpResponse` returned by the `delegate.serve(ctx, req)`:

```java
@Override
public HttpResponse serve(HttpService delegate, ServiceRequestContext ctx, HttpRequest req) {
  ... // setup session for the request context
  HttpResponse response = delegate.serve(ctx, req);
  response.whenComplete().handle((unused1, unused2) -> {
      ... // close session
  });
  return response;
}
```